# How to filter nested arrays from "null" and "undefined" values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, filter

If I have a JSON Array:

```
arrays = 
   [
      [
         undefined,
         ",",
         " ",
         "simple"
      ],
      [
         undefined,
         null,
         " ",
         "phrase"
      ],
      [
         undefined,
         ",",
         " ",
         "one"
      ],
      [
         undefined,
         null,
         " ",
         "another"
      ],
      [
         undefined,
         null,
         " ",
         "phrase"
      ]
   ]
```

Which I want to filter from `undefined` and `null` values:

```
arrays.forEach(function(array){array.filter(function(n){return !!n})});
```

or

```
arrays.forEach(function(array){array = array.filter(function(n){return !!n})});
```

But it returns the same array without any changes.

Otherwise, if I work with the inner array directly, it works:

```
rest_words[0].filter(function(n){return !!n});
=> [",", " ", "simple"]
```

Why `forEach()` doesn't allow to modify an array? Does it iterates only by value? What would be an optimal solution to modify an array by iterating it?

I hope there is something more then just iterate via `for(i=0, i<arrays.length, i++){arrays[i] = arrays[i].filter(...)}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're only assigning to the local `array` variable there, and don't write to the actual `arrays` property. You could do

```
arrays.forEach(function(array, i, all) {
    all[i] = array.filter(Boolean); // where all===arrays
});
```

but you're much better off using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create a new array:

```
refinedArrays = arrays.map(function(array) {
    return array.filter(Boolean);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Array.map()`:

```
arrays = arrays.map(function(array) {
    return array.filter(function(n){ return n != null; });
});
```

I used `n != null` which will keep any value except `null` and `undefined`.  Whereas `!!n` will exclude `""` and `0` as well.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
arrays.forEach(function(array, index){
  arrays[index] = array.filter(function(n){return !!n});
});
```